# A cross-origin error was thrown target.name

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get the attribute name of a react component.

**See this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/competent-sunset-8xcvp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)**

Here is my [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/embed/sweet-moon-mdhuf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Now from a button I can get the name of the button when that is clicked by passing the event. But what I try to do is :

```
      <div>
        <div className={"red"}>red</div>
        <div>not red</div>
        <div name={"red"} className={this.target.name === "red" ? "red" : ""}>
          dynamically allocated red
        </div>
      </div>
```

*I want if that div has name "red", that div will get color based on that*

**How can I read a component's name attribute in react.js ?**

Comment: can you please clarify what is your question? what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i want that button to render "name2" in the second button, based on that button's attribute name, which is "name2" @JigarShah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, updated my answer based on your updated question.

There are multiple ways of doing this, but I think the best one would be to create your own component that contains the required logic. So something like this:

```js
const MyComponent = ({ name, children, ...otherProps }) => {
  return (
    <div name={name} className={name === 'red' ? 'red' : ''} {...otherProps}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can then use it in your render function like this:

```js
<MyComponent>this will NOT be red</MyComponent>
<MyComponent name='red'>this one will be red</MyComponent>
<MyComponent name='blue'>this will also NOT be red</MyComponent>
```

In your example code you are using `this.target.name` which isn't possible, simply because this is not how it works. The `this` in that part of the code is referring to the current component, so `App` in your case. The `App` component does not contain a `target` property. When binding an `onClick` event the first parameter off the function will be `event`, the `event` object will contain a `target` property containing the HTML element. So in that way you can use the `name` attribute of the HTML element. But this only works because onClick receives this argument.

Comment: I updated the question clearing my requirement, can you check again, please ??

Comment: I don't want to create a new component, if there is a built in method that would be very nice..

Comment: Ok, why don't you want to create a new component? This is kind of how everything in React works. The only way I think it is possible is by storing the `name` value in a variable and then use that variable for the comparison, instead of `this.target.name`

Comment: what @japmul  said is correct you need to save the clicked data in state in your case ,so that you can access it like this.state.selectedTarget ,based on the value you can change color!,onClick action.

Comment: react doesn't support inheritance(or something we shouldn't do it react), it use composition , I'm new to composition.. and my project contains over 1000 of nav.links so how am I supposed to do so ?? @japmul that's the reason I don't want to create new object I just wanted a 'core' way to read attributes

Comment: Alright, I think you should maybe look in another direction for fixing your problem, because this is pretty much the 'core' way of doing it. If you need to apply some styling based on the name attribute you might want to go with a css solution. So target something like `div[name="red"] { background: red; }`

Comment: not trying to work with css, see this picture [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9Ziy.png), you will understand what I'm trying to achieve... @japmul

Comment: I'm trying to understand, but I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve..

Comment: @japmul check [it](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17756) out

Comment: Alright.. I assume that issue is going to be closed because it is impossible to do it like that. It is only possible when you create a new component (like my example) that will actually receive it as a prop.